# Bulk product Import examples

Tags: magento2, import

I am looking for some csv examples for bulk product uploads with or without images and i couldn't find any so far. Does anybody has or know any links, please share with me . Thanks in advance

Comment: i think you try the import product using product sku
Ex:- Sku -> 12, and image -> test.jpg this type

Comment: Did you find solution on this? I can show you csv sample if you need